# Best use of money in new technologies for the common good

Tags: technology, money

Joe Biden's "Endless Frontier Act" aims to power strategical advances in artificial intelligence and quantum technology through injection of 120 billion dollars in the American economy.

Such colossal amount of money would be able to support a workforce of about 100 000 people, for 10 years, with the addition of about 500 000 dollars each for materials and experiment.

This makes me wonder : ( I think Worldbuilding is the right place to ask this)

How to use such workforce and budget most efficiently ? What goals to pursue that are most interesting and arguably reachable within ten years ? And above all : for the common good ?

Thanks in advance for your answers.

Comment: Is there a law in America which mandates a meaning of the phrase "common good"? Because most of the time, wannabe dictators who *just know* what the common good is and direct immense resources towards it end up with decidedly mixed results at best. Which is to say, why would anybody believe that enforcing a certain understanding of where to invest available resource is better than letting people decide for themselves. (P.S. About the "colossal" amount of money: 120 billion USD is about 1/6 of the annual budget of the US War Department, that is, the Pentagon spends that in two months.)

Comment: Unfortunately I do not think any site in the network will accept this question.

Comment: Thank you for your interest and pointing at potential flaws in my line of thoughts. I did not mean to enforce anything, but at best have an idea about the current most promising areas of research. Thinking about artificial intelligence first but maybe there is better investments. As to the "common good", you are right, this is very subjective ! This is a matter of moral philosophy... Although I read about it a little, I would prefer to let this subject open to subjectivity for now. And finally, yes, wow, only 1/6 of annual budget of US war department... But still enormous in my from my perspec

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you are writing a near future history set in a fictional world which starts exactly where our real world starts now...

Create a new government entity empowered and funded to purchase critical bottleneck technology and usage patents from the corporations and individuals who created and/or currently own them.  Train up an army of technical workers in the skills needed to make the most of these technologies, then allow American companies to apply for free usage rights to these patented technologies and low priced assistance from that tech-army, in return for government oversight and first right of refusal on the patents for any resulting technology.

Identify those bottleneck technical patents whose owners are not willing to sell and assign units of your tech army to develop work arounds to bypass those patents.

Then set specific attainable goals for AI and QC applications within the government infrastructure and run quality-based competitions for contracts to develop and support those applications.

Comment: Thank you for your interest. If I understand well, your idea is first to use money to gain control of bottleneck technologies. Then gain control of emerging new technologies built upon the first ones, and so on. Using strong governmental incentives for the development of such new technologies. Then would it be worth it to first invest in identification of current bottleneck technologies ? Or are these already identified with good confidence ?

Comment: Experts may disagree but I think you could get a list of bottleneck technologies and their owners by looking at the holdings of the top AI and QC Equity Trading Funds.  Capitalism makes the identification of value easy...  just follow the money.
As for the rest of it, yes.  You have understood what I've attempted to describe.  Good luck with your project and if your last name happens to be Biden, thank you for the opportunity to help save the country.